# Why won't my discord bot go online with python and Discord API?

Tags: python, discord

I followed a tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTdaaFIHpeI&list=PLJXEdhN0Tc3LRT716enS1LcY4OF8vg1VA&index=2) to make a discord bot however, I can't get it to go online. I don't get any errors except for the runtime errors in the terminal (attached below).
I've looked for solutions on many websites and videos but still no luck.

Here is the python code from the tutorial:

```
import discord
client = discord.Client()
client.run('discord token')
```

Terminal output:

```
c:/Users/(**username**)/Desktop/Text_Adventure_Bot/Text_Adventure_Bot.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(**username**)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 300, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "C:\Users\(**username**)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in request     
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 401 Unauthorized (error code: 0): 401: Unauthorized

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\(**username**)\Desktop\Text_Adventure_Bot\Text_Adventure_Bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    client.run('discord token')
  File "C:\Users\(**username**)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 723, in run       
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\(**username**)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 702, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\(**username**)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 665, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\(**username**)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 511, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\(**username**)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 304, in static_login
    raise LoginFailure('Improper token has been passed.') from exc
discord.errors.LoginFailure: Improper token has been passed.
Exception ignored in: <function _ProactorBasePipeTransport.__del__ at 0x000001E3AEC5FDC0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(**username**)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 116, in __del__
    self.close()
  File "C:\Users\(**username**)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\proactor_events.py", line 108, in close
    self._loop.call_soon(self._call_connection_lost, None)
  File "C:\Users\(**username**)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 746, in call_soon
    self._check_closed()
  File "C:\Users\(**username**)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 510, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Comment: It appears that you have used an incorrect token. Check it again.

Comment: You were right, Thank you!